# The phrase "in the early morning, just after one" does not make sense to me

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

> They had come to fire the house, their visit expected because they had
> been before. On that occasion they had come later, **in the early morning,
> just after one**. The sheepdogs had seen them off, but within a week the
> dogs lay poisoned in the yard and Captain Gault knew that the intruders
> would be back.

I think when we say "in the early morning" we mean for example 4 AM

In this context, is the meaning of "early morning" the start of the other day, which starts after 12 o'clock?

Source: *[The Story of Lucy Gault](https://books.google.it/books?id=iUbrNQWxDioC&pg=PT9&dq=%E2%80%9Cin%20the%20early%20morning,%20just%20after%20one%E2%80%9C&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit7JWLzsDtAhWL5OAKHeWjBt8Q6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Cin%20the%20early%20morning%2C%20just%20after%20one%E2%80%9C&f=false)* by William Trevor

Comment: What do you mean by 12 o'clock? Midnight or midday? Big difference.

Comment: I mean midnight or 24 o'clock.

Comment: 24 o'clock is never said, it's either 24.00 or 12 o'clock midnight. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152603/why-11-am-1-hour-1200-pm

Answer (score 1):

Early morning would describe the time after midnight. So in this case “early morning just after one” would imply a time just after 1 am.

So yes,

**Dose in this context the purpose of "early morning" is the start of the other day which it starts after 12 oclock?**

Is correct.

Comment: The difference between "early in the morning" and "late at night" is all about perspective and has less to do with the clock. There is no firm boundary between the two. Late at night gives the sense of being up for a long time before. Early in the morning gives the sense of being up early. 4 am is late at night for a gamer, but early in the morning for an athlete waking up to train.

Comment: Yes that is true it is all about perspective. However to be specific early in the morning is after midnight as any time before then is not considered early in the morning.

Comment: I've corrected the spelling of "dose" and edited the question to be more grammatical. It doesn't affect your answer, but you might want to consider editing the quotation as a result.